# NSURLConnection in a class alone

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsurlconnection

I want to be able to, let's say, run a NSURLConnection post and download like this:

```
NSString *data = [Server post:para1, para2, para3];
```

I'm pretty sure that I have to write a class containing the delegates of NSURLConnection and of course the function called post initiating the NSURLConnection and returning the downloaded string.

The whole problem is that I don't know how to do this correctly. I've tried adding a class called Server with the delegates and such, and then making the function post public. Afterwards, the post function was not able to access the delegates and variables in the class. Furthermore, the post function had no way to return the string, since it was first known in the `- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection`.

Can you please give me a hint how to make a class, that can HTTP POST to a URL and return the string and be run with only one or a few lines?

Comment: Are you sure this is what you want? This will have to be a blocking call, as the connection could be extremely slow. Additionally, it might fail.

Comment: I think this will be the easiest, yes. I will start it in another thread to prevent the app from freezing. The reason why I want it, is because the NSURLConnection will run mulitple times returning different values and needs to be handled differently. It seems very difficult to "guess" which string is returned in - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a synchronous URL request (preferably in a non-main thread) you can use the

```
sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:
```

class method of `NSURLConnection`.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this in two ways, one would be to have a custom delegate which gets called when the connectionDidFinishLoading has finished or you could provide your Server method a block callback which gets called when it is complete. Blocks are a bit confusing to start with but are a very good tool to know how to use.

Have a look at [Blocks (Apple Doc)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html)

[Bock Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/9328/creating-a-diner-app-using-blocks-part-1)